# Portlet from liferay documentation

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

Hi i try do portlet from liferay documentation. But my java class dont work.

MyGreetingPortlet

```
package com.liferay.samples;  
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest; 
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse; 
import javax.portlet.PortletException; 
import javax.portlet.PortletPreferences; 
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;  
public class MyGreetingPortlet extends MVCPortlet { @Override 
public void processAction( ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) 
        throws IOException, PortletException { 
    PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences(); 
    String greeting = actionRequest.getParameter("greeting");  
    if (greeting != null) { 
        prefs.setValue("greeting", greeting); 
        prefs.store();
        }  
    super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse); 
    } 
}
```

view.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %> 
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %> 
<portlet:defineObjects />
<% PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
String greeting = (String)prefs.getValue( "greeting", "Hello! Welcome to our portal."); %>
<p><%= greeting %></p>
<portlet:renderURL var="editGreetingURL"> <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" /> 
</portlet:renderURL> 
<p><a href="<%= editGreetingURL %>">Edit greeting</a></p>
```

edit.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %> 
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil" %> 
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator" %> 
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %>  
<portlet:defineObjects />  
<% PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences(); 
String greeting = (String)prefs.getValue( "greeting", "Hello! Welcome to our portal."); %>  
<portlet:actionURL var="editGreetingURL"> <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" /> 
</portlet:actionURL>  
<form action="<%= editGreetingURL %>" method="post"> 
<label><input type="text"><%= greeting %></label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>  
<portlet:renderURL var="viewGreetingURL"> 
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/view.jsp" /> 
</portlet:renderURL>  
<p><a href="<%= viewGreetingURL %>">&larr; Back</a></p>
```

After deploy jsp works fine, but when i click on Submit button nothing heppens. I change only one thing in this example: delete aui tags but dont think that chage something, couse im already try a few diffetent examples and no one works with java classes. Oh, and i use MVC portlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your portlet-class in portlet.xml is not pointing to the custom portlet class of yours and is still referring MVCPortlet. Please change that to point your custom portlet class

**---Update---**

After checking your code in my local found that the way you are passing parameter is incorrect. You are not passing the name of the parameter. You should pass the parameter like shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>greeting"><%= greeting %></input>
```

Comment: i change portlet-class to my portlet in portlet.xml.

Comment: Any error in the log. How are you sure that clicking submit doesnt call processAction of MyGreeting portlet. Can you put some log statement or System.out.println in processAction method of your portlet class

Comment: I dont see any erorrs. Its example from here http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/understanding-the-two-phases-of-portlet-executi-4

Comment: Not sure, why you are getting error unless I see your complete portlet. Can you upload the portlet source(may be zip it) of yours in dropbox or something and share the link, so that I can see why its not working

Comment: I checked your code. When submitting the form, processAction is getting called correctly. Only problem is when you are submitting the form, you are not passing the greeting parameter name. You are passing <input type="text"> but it should be <input type="text" name="greeting">

Comment: But can u show me how to use doView() in portlet? How it can be added in this portlet just for demonstration?

Comment: Sure override the doView method. And do a simple SOP. It should get printed out on every page refresh, on maximized state and before the portlet is rendered

Answer (score 2):

The file portlet.xml also needs to be changed so that it points to our new class

```
 <portlet>
    <portlet-name>my-greeting</portlet-name>
    <display-name>My Greeting</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.liferay.samples.MyGreetingPortlet</portlet-
    class>
    <init-param>
    <name>view-jsp</name>
    <value>/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
```

In edit.jsp

```
<%
    PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
    String greeting = (String) prefs.getValue("greeting",
            "Hello! Welcome to our portal.");
%>
```

After this add the below code

```
<liferay-ui:success key="success" message="Greeting saved successfully!" />
```

Regenerate the war file you will see the output. Still, if you face the problem, I will provide the complete code

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not necessary to call

```
super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
```

remove it and try again, then it might work.